# Cannot execute binary file

Tags: bash, binary

I am new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to install Popcorn Time.
I downloaded 32 bit version and tried to install it but that's where the problem started showing.

I double clicked the executable file and well, nothing happened. It's a official download from their website but it doesn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong... Anyway, I found out that you can install it from a script, but people keep talking in Ubuntu terms and I don't understand it, so I have a few questions:

1. How to make a script? (which I'm suppose to run in terminal using bash command),
2. Is it normal that i cannot run the installer, and if that is an installer or just files for the program.
3. If it is an installer, how do I make it work?
4. What does " Cannot execute binary file" mean?

Thank you in advance, hope I'm not asking too many questions (please understand that I'm new to Ubuntu) and sorry about my English. xD

Comment: did you download it in archive?

Comment: Please add the version of Ubuntu you are using and the name of the file.

Comment: There is a very simple way to install Popcorn Time with only three commands from an terminal. Look at this link [Install Popcorn Time In Ubuntu Or Debian Via PPA Repository](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/install-popcorn-time-in-ubuntu-or.html) follow the description below "To add the WebUpd8 Popcorn Time PPA and install the app in Ubuntu / Linux Mint"

Answer (score 2):

## Question 1

Scripts are simple and fun to write in ubuntu/linux . Here are some good links that really helped me.

Mind the syntax though.

http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/
http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Main_Page
http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/08/getting-started-linux-shell-scripting.html

## Question 2

Yes it is really normal that you are unable to run that installer as that might not be your system specific installer.Ubuntu can easily understand .deb , .rpm , .sh also .exe but using a special software called WINE.

[here's an article for installing wine if you need it.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine)

## Question 3

Linux is secure so it might have made your installer dysfunctional.In other words might have made it non-executable.So you make it executable by following this.

```
1. right click on that installer.
2. open permissions tab
3. check the option that says "allow executing file as a program"
4. press close button.

Now double click that file and you should see a box saying display , run in terminal and some others.

Press run in terminal.
```

Now you may get some other errors or it will run perfectly if it is right for your OS.

## Question 4

This simply means this is not an ready to execute file.So make it executable using the answer to question 3.

I have tried to talk in non-ubuntu terminology as much as possible.I hope it helps you.